# Better way to convert HTML/CSS into Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, google-chrome, html2canvas

I'm creating web app, that allows create simple add banners. You can add elements on a banner (text, images, boxes, etc.) drag&drop, resize them, change it's properties.

Just to get a better idea, here is how it looks:

[image: Application screen]

In the banner editor, elements are simple HTML with inline styles.

To covert created HTML into image i use library - [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). It basically renders HTML on a canvas, that can be saved as image. But it has limitaions (not all css properties are supported) and the result image is different then preview sometimes.

So my questions are:

- Is there a better way to do it?
- Is it possible to make a screenshot of the part of the page and save it as image?
- Is there a way to render HTML with CSS on server? Scince NodeJs uses v8 engine maybe there is a way to render HTML/CSS with it?

I don't need cross browser solution. It's fine if it will work in chrome only.

Comment: You can render it on server with PhantomJS or other similar solution.

Comment: HTML > Canvas > IMAGE See  tutorial here http://www.freakyjolly.com/convert-html-document-into-image-jpg-png-from-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

Check it out https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/283 - may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use html2Canvas library to convert **HTML** >> **Canvas** >> **Image**(PNG or JPG)

```
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("image-wrap")).then(function(canvas) {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.download = "manpower_efficiency.jpg";
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            link.target = '_blank';
            link.click();
        });
```

**Source**: http://www.freakyjolly.com/convert-html-document-into-image-jpg-png-from-canvas/